# Making imports available around your code

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mef

In my [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) usage, I have a bunch of imports that I want to make available in many other parts of my code. Something like:

```
[Export (typeof (IBarProvider))]
class MyBarFactory : IBarPovider
{
    [Import]
    public IFoo1Service IFoo1Service { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IFoo2Service IFoo2Service { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IFoo3Service IFoo3Service { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IFoo4Service IFoo4Service { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IFoo5Service IFoo5Service { get; set; }

    public IBar CreateBar()
    {
        return new BarImplementation(/* want to pass the imported services here */);
    }
}

class BarImplementation : IBar
{
    readonly zib zib;

    public BarImplementation(/* ... */)
    {
        this.zib = new Zib(/* pass services here, too */);
    }
}
```

I could pass each imported service as an individual parameter, but it's a lot of boring code.  There's gotta be something better.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this answers your question but have you considered using the constructor injection yet?

```
class BarImplementation : IBar
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public BarImplementation(IFoo1Service foo1, IFoo2Service foo2, ...) { }
}
```

By marking your constructor with the ImportingConstructor attribute it will essentially make all the parameters of that constructor required imports.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about making an interface to provide these services:

```
partial class BarImplementation
{
    public IRequiredServices
    {

        public IFoo1Service IFoo1Service { get; set; }
        public IFoo2Service IFoo2Service { get; set; }  
        public IFoo3Service IFoo3Service { get; set; }          
        public IFoo4Service IFoo4Service { get; set; }      
        public IFoo5Service IFoo5Service { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then `MyBarFactory` implements `BarImplementation : BarImplementation.IRequiredServices`.  That's easy to write, but then, how do I pass them down to `Zib`?  I don't want to couple `Zib` to its consumer that way.

Answer (score 0):

I could make `IImports` an interface that contains all the services I import, pass that around everywhere, and then classes can use or not use whichever they like.  But that couples all the classes toegether.

Comment: This is essentially the route that I went down. All of my modules have an IHost property that I set once I've loaded them. IHost can then have a list of loaded modules...